# Where did these yaml.customTags come from in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I looked in my settings.json file recently in vs code and found a bunch of yaml custom tags that I did not add. These are being added to the config in every workspace when I open it.

I thought maybe these were added by a recent AWS Toolkit extension update but I removed AWS Toolkit entirely and they remained.  I cannot identify another plugin that I've added that has anything to do with YAML and I've added no plugins recently.

Here is the list.

```
"yaml.customTags": [
    "!And",
    "!And sequence",
    "!If",
    "!If sequence",
    "!Not",
    "!Not sequence",
    "!Equals",
    "!Equals sequence",
    "!Or",
    "!Or sequence",
    "!FindInMap",
    "!FindInMap sequence",
    "!Base64",
    "!Join",
    "!Join sequence",
    "!Cidr",
    "!Ref",
    "!Sub",
    "!Sub sequence",
    "!GetAtt",
    "!GetAZs",
    "!ImportValue",
    "!ImportValue sequence",
    "!Select",
    "!Select sequence",
    "!Split",
    "!Split sequence"
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this annoying bug and raised a GitHub issue in the YAML extension repo where this problem came from - hopefully they fix it.  I see it because I have Atlassian's JIRA extension installed, which is quite handy.   Worse yet, you can't just disable or remove the YAML extension without also disabling the JIRA extension.

https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/578

**Update**: Turns out this is actually related to a combination of the "AWS Toolkit" extension alongside the "YAML" extension.   While the setting is related to the YAML extension, it doesn't cause the problem by itself.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/1933) is actively addressing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may have YAML Language Support by Red Hat Extension installed.

"yaml.customTags" is documented at:
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml